# Artifactory how many repository can I create?

Tags: docker, repository, artifactory

I have artifactory pro license.

I want to use the artifactory for docker repository.

As you know, docker repository support user namespace like this,

example.com/username/imagename:tag

but artifactory use repository name instead of username.

but i wanna to use username space and apply permission for each user for their repository.

so, how many repository supported?

Answer (score 4):

Using an Artifactory pro myself, I confirm a docker registry support as many namespace (not just username) as you would need.

All I need to do is:

- login

  ```
  docker login my-registry
  ```
- tag

  ```
  docker tag my_tag my-registry:my_label/my_tag
  ```
- push

  ```
  docker push my-registry:my_label/my_tag
  ```

With "`my-registry`" being the name of the server referencing your artifactory docker registry, as configured by "[Configuring Artifactory / Configuring a Reverse Proxy / Configuring NGINX](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+NGINX) "

That is because Docker requires the URL of any repository it connects to conform to a specific format (`http(s)://<host>:<port>/v1`), and Artifactory requires a specific URL format (`http://<host>:<port>/artifactory/api/docker/<docker_repository>`).
Hence the need for a reverse proxy.

But: there is no notion of username, only namespace.
As mentioned in [Artifactory Docker Registry](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Docker+Registry):

> With the fine-grained access control provided by built-in security features, Artifactory offers secure Docker push and pull with local Docker repositories as fully functional, secure, private Docker registries.

But those [built-in security features](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Security) are for user authentication to Artifactory in general, not specific to a docker registry which has no notion of username: if a user has permission of pushing to a docker registry, it pushing to any part of it.

> I want is to perform ACLs on a namespace basis.

As far as I know, this would not be supported.
You might configure NGiNX to filter that for you, but Artifactory itself does not provide docker registry namespace-based ACL.

---

> So I want to create a repository for each user and grant permission to that repository to use an artifactory like a docker hub. So I'm wondering how many repositories I can create in an artifactory

That implies two things:

- different local docker repositories: there are no official limit to the number of repos, [only local storage quota limits](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Local+Repositories).
- different NGiNX reverse proxied domain names: each separate registry needs to have its own domain name.

Comment: thanks your comment, but what I want is to perform ACLs on a namespace basis. 
As you know, this method does not allocate private space per user.

Comment: @HanminBang Yes, I made that clearer in my edited answer.

Comment: thanks a lot, 
So I want to create a repository for each user and grant permission to that repository to use an artifactory like a docker hub.
So I'm wondering how many repositories I can create in an artifactory.

Comment: @HanminBang OK. I have edited my answer accordingly.